# Using Custom Labels in a controller

Tags: customlabel

have the below statements using some hard coded strings and I want to make them use as custom labels. So how can I make these statements to use the Custom Labels I created ? custom label:- value A,B,C

```
else if((caseList[i].gp == 'A' || caseList[i].gp == 'B' || caseList[i].gp == 'C') && (caseList[i+1].gp == 'A' || caseList[i+1].gp == 'B' || caseList[i+1].gp == 'C'))
```

Comment: create a custom label with value 'A' and name "Avalue". use (eg) if(caseList[i].gp==Lable.Avalue

Comment: what is not working. You are getting any error? Also this is working with static values?

Comment: yes thers a value assets/contact(for eg:-A)it is throwing an error

Comment: Can you provide more details. as it is hard to give any solution using info provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them like

```
System.Label.A, System.Label.B, System.Label.C
```

More details you can check here [Custom label in Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US).

First create three separate labels. then do something like

```
else if((caseList[i].gp == System.Label.A || caseList[i].gp == System.Label.B || caseList[i].gp == System.Label.C) && (caseList[i+1].gp == System.Label.A || caseList[i+1].gp == System.Label.B || caseList[i+1].gp == System.Label.C))
```

Comment: i have only one custom label and the values A,B,C are in that label how can i use it?

Comment: you create three custom labels for A ,B and C

Comment: Tushar thanks but its not working

Comment: Btw, you can use Labels without `System` keyword, just `Label.yourLabelName` in apex.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Label.
Value =A name="Avalue"
Value =B name="Bvalue"
Value =C name="Cvalue"

Eg;

```
else if((caseList[i].gp == Label.Avalue || caseList[i].gp == Label.Bvalue ||    caseList[i].gp == Label.Cvalue) && (caseList[i+1].gp ==Label.Avalue || caseList[i+1].gp == Label.Bvalue || caseList[i+1].gp == Label.Cvalue))
```